# How to integrate JIRA ticketing with ASP.NET Application

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

We have ASP.NET MVC applications. We have our own `IdP` for SSO, The `IdP` issues authentication ticket using OpenID Connect Protocol. Users can access all our applications by singing once.

We want to use JIRA ticketing system for users to create ticket.

1. We can create account for every user and provide link on UI to JIRA to create ticket. However that is not convenient if we have large number of users, and keep growing.
2. We can also create a `form` in our applications and then submit the form to JIRA using their API. However I am trying to avoid this option because then I have create `form` in every application and maintain it.

Ideal optional would be, when user clicks on the create ticket link, it should get redirected to JIRA ticketing system, MUST get authenticated implicitly (maybe using access token) and be able to create ticket using JIRA's ticketing system.

Is this possible? Can someone please provide guidelines

Comment: Take a look to the [SSO add-ons for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?product=jira&query=SSO)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using JIRA's built-in IssueCollector.
This is super simple to set up, and you can find more info [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/using-the-issue-collector-802592637.html)

Unless you need to do something really custom, then this should work out of the box.